# How to hide multiple datepicker calender same id document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, css, reporting-services, datepicker

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello , I've been working on the Date picker for the report viewer when i add  datepicker hidden field reportViewer and add the code bellow in to ReportViewer Master page when i preview my report i got two of datepicker carlendar (in the red one is defaul ) and i add  document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';  to hide the defaul one but hide only the first datepicker and the second one is still show. How to hide these two datepicker (inside the red id =ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton)

```
 function fixParameters() {
        if ($.browser.webkit) {

            // add date picker
            $($(":hidden[id*='datepicker']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
                var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                    var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                    //  var vs = $("input[id=*='ParametersGrid']").is(':checked');
                    return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);

                }).parent("td").next("td").find('input[type="text"]:not(:has(input[type="checkbox"]))').datepicker({
                    showOn: "button"
                     , buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif'                      
                   , buttonImageOnly: true
                   , dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                   , changeMonth: true
                   , changeYear: true
                   , showOtherMonths: true
                    , inline: true
                   , selectOtherMonths: true,
                });
            });

            // remove time from date
            $($(":hidden[id*='datepicker']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
                var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                    var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                    return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
                }).parent("td").next("td").find("input").parent().children("input").each(function () {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 10));
                });
            });
        }
            //} 
   the resaon that i add else because i want the IE,firefox to have the same datepicker style 
      else {

            document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';

            $($(":hidden[id*='datepicker']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
                var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                    var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                    //  var vs = $("input[id=*='ParametersGrid']").is(':checked');
                    return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);

                }).parent("td").next("td").find('input[type="text"]:not(:has(input[type="checkbox"]))').datepicker({
                    showOn: "button"
                    // , buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif'
                    , buttonImage: 'Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.40219.329&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif'
                   , buttonImageOnly: true
                   , dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                   , changeMonth: true
                   , changeYear: true
                   , showOtherMonths: true
                    , inline: true
                   , selectOtherMonths: true,
                });
            });

            // remove time from date
            $($(":hidden[id*='datepicker']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
                var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                    var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                    return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
                }).parent("td").next("td").find("input").parent().children("input").each(function () {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 10));
                });
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why can't you use a single component in the page that will address all browser types? JqueryUI datepicker supports multiple browsers http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: The ReportViewer dons't support datepicker so when i preview my report on Chrome  the datepicker calendar were disappear then i have to add  <asp:HiddenField ID="datepicker" runat="server" /> to the reportviewer and add javascript to reportViewer master page. everything is work great but when click on carlendar between Chrome vs IE were different style , then  i add else {  continue next comment

Comment: I add the code above  if ($.browser.webkit) to check if chrome display the date picker that and else on the IE to display the datepicker the same style as chrome but instead of display only the new datepicker style on IE also display the default datepicker then i added document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton').style.visibility = 'hidden'; to hide the default one but work only the first the second still there (see the second image)

Comment: I'm not sure if I have misunderstood, but if you have two elements with the same ID in the DOM, only the first one will be recognised by jQuery because IDs must be unique - you cannot have two elements with the same ID at the same time.

Comment: James you are right about this. thank you for your answered, I've found the solution by adding style for id to be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by adding styling for the default datepicker calendar to hide

```
#ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl05_ddDropDownButton {
 visibility: hidden;
```

}